# Python cv2.remap from mesh creates pixelated distortions

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have a mesh that is 4 times smaller than an image, I want to distort the image with the information from the mesh but, when using cv2.remap it makes the distortion pixelated (See image below) . How could I make a smoother distortion?

Original:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

My output:

[image]

My code:

```
img = np.array(Image.open('astronaut.jpg')) # Shape -> (512, 512, 3)
mesh = Mesh('astronaut.msh').get_uvs() # Shape -> (128, 128, 2), 2 channels for x and y 

new_mesh = np.zeros((img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 2))
new_mesh[:,:,0] = np.repeat(np.repeat(mesh[:,:,0], 4, axis=0), 4, axis=1)
new_mesh[:,:,1] = np.repeat(np.repeat(mesh[:,:,1], 4, axis=0), 4, axis=1)

nh, nw = img.shape[:2]
xs, ys = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, nw), np.arange(0, nh))
xs = xs + new_mesh[:,:,0] * 4 # multiply by constant to modulate distort strength
ys = ys + new_mesh[:,:,1] * 4
xs = np.float32(xs)
ys = np.float32(ys)

dst= cv2.remap(img.astype(np.uint8), xs, ys, cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Comment: The desired output was generated using `PiecewiseAffineTransform` and `warp` from `skimage`. It takes forever and cv2.remap appears to be much faster.

Comment: those artefacts come from `np.repeat`. you're not interpolating properly, **you just copy 4x4 patches.** that's worse than nearest-neighbor interpolation, four times worse to be exact. OpenCV is not to blame. blame the construction of your maps. properly upsample your mesh (`np.repeat` is wrong), then you get good results.

Comment: please provide a [mre]. your question lacks the mesh you reference in your code. I can't write a proper answer until I can reproduce and build upon your code.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but well as you said it is the 4x4 repetition patches. I created a more linear resample with numpy linespace and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV is not to blame. It does exactly what you tell it to.

Those artefacts come from your use of `np.repeat`. That merely *repeats* each index element in your map array. You're not upsampling your mesh properly, **you effectively just copy 4x4 patches** with that code.

Properly upsample your mesh (`np.repeat` is wrong), then you get good results. You can easily do that using `cv.resize` and *anything other than* nearest-neighbor interpolation. If you need to control boundary behavior exactly, you'll need warpAffine and a custom transformation matrix. You could even use `cv.pyrUp` (twice).

When you've presented a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (some data for the mesh), I'll update my answer with working code.

Comment: You are correct, I created a linear space between the patches and that solved the problem!